# Want to get specific data from a webpage

Tags: php

I am trying hard to get data from following portion of a webpage

```
<div id="menu_pannel">
 <ul class="sf-menu" id="nav">
    <li  class="current"><a href="/" class="current" >Home</a></li>

    <li class=""><a href="/schedule.php" class="" target="_blank">Schedule</a></li>

    <li class=""><a href="/categories/" class="">All Channels</a></li>

    <li class=""><a href="#" class="">Sports Channels</a>

         <ul id="submenu">
        <li><a href="http://www.time4tv.com/2011/01/sky-sports-1.php">Sky Sports 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.time4tv.com/2011/02/sky-sports-2.php">Sky Sports 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.time4tv.com/2011/03/sky-sports-3.php">Sky Sports
```

I want to get data from  for that i am using

```
$pattern = '|<ul id="nav" class="sf-menu">(.*?)</ul>|';

preg_match($pattern, $html, $data);
```

but getting emty array .

Comment: what exactly do you want from the regex? each li?

Comment: First, don't parse HTML with regex. Sooner or later, your eyes will start bleeding. Use a parser instead. Second, look at this part of your regex: `<ul id="nav" class="sf-menu">`. Now look at the HTML. What's wrong with this picture?

Comment: you have missed closing tag for `<ul class="sf-menu" id="nav">`

Answer (score 0):

Use `DOMDocument` class for manipulating HTML content:

```
// $html_str is your html fragment
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html_str);
$ul_content = "";

$ul = $doc->getElementsByTagName("ul")->item(0);
if ($ul && $ul->getAttribute('class') == 'sf-menu') {
    foreach ($ul->childNodes as $n) {
        $ul_content .= $doc->saveHTML($n);
    }
}

echo $ul_content;
```

Comment: I wouldn't paste it without a test. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3435803eb3414bcd606ddae1dd626f794be7b5a4

Comment: Theree is problem with getElementById("nav") in DomDocument. It returns nothing :(

Comment: *It returns nothing* - doesn't seem to be true. I returns `object(DOMElement) ...` for me

Comment: I wouldn't rely on `eval.in` . It has limited PHP versions set(5.5).

Comment: @splash58 Though it works on my local machine, I suppose `getAttribute` may not work in some particular cases. Changed to `getElementsByTagName` for better compatibility

Comment: I think it's better to loop result of getElementsByTagName  because we see just *portion of a webpage*, and so it can be not the 1st `ul`

Comment: the OP presented a certain portion of html and within that portion it would be the 1th `ul`

Answer (score 0):

if strip_tags($html) doesn't returns what you want, you can use this example to get an array of text:

```
function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname) {
    preg_match_all("#<$tagname.*?>([^<]+)</$tagname>#", $string, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}
$values = getTextBetweenTags ($html, 'a' );
foreach($values as $value) {
    echo $value . '<br>';
}
```

where $html is a var containing your html.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use dom parser

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str);   
$x = new DomXpath($doc);
$ul = $x->query('//ul[@id="nav"]'); // 'id' is a unique identifier!
// Echo outerHTML of ul[@id="nav"]
echo $doc->saveHTML($ul->item(0));
```

[demo](https://eval.in/599612)

Comment: @splash58 now i have got problem to use $doc as i want to get a list of each item and then display it in a span.                                         $pattern = '|<a href="([^"]+)" title="[^"]+"\s* class="([^"]+)">([^<]+)</a>|';           preg_match_all($pattern, $doc[0], $cats, PREG_SET_ORDER);       Where   cats is the each entity in the array.   output for $doc[0] is following                                                                                              Sky Sports 1
Sky Sports 2
Sky Sports 3
Sky Sports 4
Sky Sports 5